# Get current page URL and Title from a Provider Hosted add-in Part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, azure, cross-domain

I'm looking to see if there is a way to grab the current URL and title of the page that the add-in part is residing on. The add-in part is a Provider Hosted add-in with the main piece living outside of SharePoint. I am using JSOM at the moment to grab the Client Context and Web Context.

I understand that the cross domain scripting is preventing me from using traditional `window.top.location.href`.

Does anyone know of any tips or tricks that I may be missing to grab information that would otherwise be relatively easy to grab.

SharePoint is essentially using Cross-Domain scripting and a proxy page to share information between SharePoint and Azure. I need to grab the parent window of the iFrame of the proxy page.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that? Do you want to store some config data specific for that add-in part?

Comment: I have an app that attempting to track which page (title and URL) the action within the app was taken upon. Think of a survey. The information is added to a database related to the user. The add-in can be added to any page on the Site Collection.

Comment: Similar need here - I need to check the page permissions of the user who is opening the page to display content depending on those permissions. No solution yet.